# HTML entities in Textile

Tags: html-entities, textile, redcloth

HTML entities are not displayed correctly in Textile because the ampersand is converted into `&amp;` by the system. **Is there any way to input e.g. `&#x2318;` and actually get ⌘?**

Wrapping the entity in `==&#x2318;==` does disable Textile processing for that block. Maybe that's as good as it gets?

I'm using RedCloth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having had a look through RedCloth sources, there does not seem to be a way of doing this.

Maybe it's as well, on second thought: Textile is not *necessarily* meant to output HTML, but HTML entities are entirely an HTML solution. I'll just input funky characters directly.

Answer (score 0):

RedCloth does not get hex values in html entities, but others, like `&nbsp;` or `&#8364;` are processed properly.